# Is there a Spring annotation that replaces ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.getBean?

Tags: java, spring

I have defined a class MyFrontService in a jar, here is how I want to use it:

```
import blabla.MyFrontService;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFrontService.doThis();
    }
}
```

The FrontService serves as an entry point to access other services.
Here is how it is currently defined (and it works).

MyFrontService.java:

```
public class MyFrontService {

    public static void doThis(){

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/springBeans.xml");
        MyService1 myService1 = (MyService1) context.getBean("myService1");
        myService1.doSomething();
        context.close();

    }
}
```

MyService1.java:

```
package blabla.service;

@Service("myService1")
public class MyService1 {

    public void doSomething(){
        // some code
    }
}
```

src/main/resources/META-INF/springBeans.xml:

```
(...)
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="blabla.service" />
(...)
```

I would like to replace the code of MyFrontService.java by something like this:

```
@MagicAnnotation("what_path?/springBeans.xml")
public class MyFrontService {

    @Autowired
    private static MyService1 myService1;

    public static void doThis(){
        myService1.doSomething();            
    }
}
```

I've read a lot from other questions on this website and others. It is sometimes said that it's impossible, and sometimes annotations like @Configuration, @Import and others are used but I can't make them work. For example, using

```
@ImportResource("classpath:META-INF/springBeans.xml")
```

triggers a NullPointerException when calling myService1.doSomething().

If it is possible to do it, what annotation and what path should I use?

Comment: No, there is no magic. Something has to process annotations. That something is Spring. If you don't tell Spring to do it through initializing an `ApplicationContext`, how is it supposed to know to do it?

Comment: The entry point of any Spring-based app is an `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: Also, Spring doesn't do `@Autowired` with `static` anything.

Comment: I assume that there is no reason to define Spring beans without instantiate them. That's why I thought that there was maybe a way to specify the xml file and instantiate the beans at once.

Comment: I don't understand that question. Your provide a context configuration to the `ApplicationContext` and it will instantiate your beans for you. You just have to retrieve them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Spring Boot](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot) framework and you will be able to write smth like this

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleController.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if you mark your class MyFrontService with @Component annotation that should save the headache of doing all the stuff you are doing. if you dont want to add the annotation and dont want to have everything under spring config you can define a class as below.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

public class SpringContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;  


    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
          return applicationContext;
        }


    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(
            org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext ctx)
            throws BeansException {
        applicationContext = ctx;
    }


}
```

And then in any class you can do,

```
ApplicationContext ctx  = SpringContextUtil.getApplicationContext();
        BeanClass av    = ctx.getBean(BeanClass.class);
```

Comment: What's calling `setApplicationContext` here?

Comment: just register that bean in your dispatcher servlet and that should do the work of setting it.

Comment: What makes you think this is a Servlet application?

Comment: @pillar when you defining springBeans.xml you are defining the dispatcher servlet. please read the content carefully, before voting down or up.

Comment: I can define and and initialize an application context with an XML without being in a web application. Nothing in their question indicates they are using a web application. Even if there were, they're are much better ways to do what they want than what you are suggesting.

Comment: @Pillar agreed, is there a class which starts the app, if any. you can call the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/springBeans.xml"); there and thats it. but still i agree with what you say.

Comment: Their question is about not having to manage an `ApplicationContext`, but instead have some `MagicAnnotation` that does it for you.

Comment: @EnableAutoConfiguration deos everything for us, but if we want to have some magic annotation lets refer the class https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java

Comment: You have to be careful how you explain it. `@EnableAutoConfiguration` doesn't do anything on its own. `SpringApplication` does. And it does so through an `ApplicationContext`.